# Height not adjusting for a social platform game?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, opensocial

I am porting a Unity based game to Mixi and have a small webpage below for FAQ etc. based on jQuery UI tabs. I am using

```
gadgets.window.adjustHeight(1200);
```

as per documentation on Mixi platform given [here](http://developer.mixi.co.jp/en/appli/ns/pc/adjust_iframe/)

It works perfectly on Chrome, but doesn't work on Firefox and IE.
I have tried on DOM ready and also after whole body loads but result is the same. Even if I call it without explicit value for height(which acc. to docs means calculate height acc. to contents, it does not work !)
I have also tried an approach from an answer in a similar thread on the internet by doing:
    gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler(init);
and then calling adjustHeight in init() but that does not work on any browser.

It is a simple opensocial container. But, I do not know if there is any other way to adjust height of the iFrame on a social platform page. Is there any ?

The JS console is not giving any error. If you need any other info, please let me know.